# Creating a test blockchain that can sync with other nodes

Tags: testnets, nodes, staking, validators, liquid-staking

I'd like to create a test Blockchain to experiment on Liquid staking.
It would require to have several nodes to be able to sync together and have several validators on this testnet.

However the only solutions I found are:

- To create a local testnest
- Use a deployed testnet such as Goërli

The problem is that I would need to have both **a high amount of fake Ether** AND to be able to **share this blockchain and let others create nodes and sync** with them.
It seems impossible to have both.

I'd like to use this test Blockchain to have multiple validators and implement Liquid staking.

What would be the best way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create your own network. there's no real difference between testnet and mainnet except to network-id and history.

So I would just use geth to spin your own network, setup a bootnode with exposed IP and let others connect to you. you should also share a genesis file with them which can probably include addresses of accounts with pre-set eth.